# returning arithmetic operators in java

Tags: java, android, performance

I am working on a program that returns arithmetic expressions which include operators and integer numbers. The code that i have implemented for it is this :

```
public String randomOperators() {
    Random random = new Random();
    String[] operators = {"+","-","*","/"};
    return operators[random.nextInt(4)];
}
```

the problem in this code is that it returns the operators but all the operators in the expression are same: 
example:  i get an expression 9+2+3+4+5+ = ? 
i don't want it to have + in all, it can be many random operators in one expression. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: In addition to @LouisWasserman's answer below, doing random.nextInt(operators.length) is preferred, so you can add/remove operators and not break the random selection.

Answer (score 3):

`new Random()` initializes the random seed with an approximation of the current time, so if called many times in quick succession, the system clock will read the same -- and the random numbers generated will be the same.

Instead, have one `Random` stored as a static field, or pass in a `Random` to `randomOperators` and reuse that same instance.